# How Build ChatScript in VS2017

Tags: chatscript

I am trying to develop a chatbot that will query data in an elasticsearch database ... I have seen the project code in MongoDb and I believe that maybe I can develop a module to connect also in Elasticsearch .... But this last revision 8.31 does not compile the Project in VS2017

I have received an error of duktape.c not found in the project and if I delete this file I just received errors LNK2019 Symbol extern indefined ... without the possibility of trying to develop ....

Is there any procedure I might be doing to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Reacquire the VS2017 folder from ChatScript github.  Or delete from files list duktape.c and add back duktape.cpp (the revised name of the file)